# Почему функция click() не вызывается?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="click()">Click</button>
    <script>
    function click() {
        console.log('Hello world');
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте зарезервированные методы элементов HTML для имен функций, которые вы передаете в строковые значения атрибутов **on***.

Например для **click()** и **button**, запись **onclick="click()"** интерпритируется как вызов **button.click()** т.к. у **button** есть метод **click**

Назовите функцию по другому и заработает

```
function myClick() {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

> Однако!

Т.к. функция создается в **window**, то сработает, если мы вызовем функцию следующим образом **window.click()**

```
<button onclick="window.click()">Click</button>
<script>
function click() {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что вы правильную цитату предоставили, ключевые слова это слова по типу: `function`, `class`, `let`, `const` и т.п. Никогда не видел чтобы кто-то где-то использовал в обыкновенном JS ключ. слово `click`.

Comment: Перепроверил список ключ. слов в MDN, там нигде не упоминается `click`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ответ поправил

Comment: Хм, впервые вижу такую особенность, есть ли какие-то другие события с похожим поведением при такой ситуации?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Порыскал, вот тут нашел описание, как это в целом работает [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388443/javascript-function-name-cannot-set-as-click). Можно поэкспериментировать, скорее всего для всех событий будет такая шляпа. В паре мест нашел ссылку на домунтацию w3.org но ничего не нашел

Comment: Окей, в любом случае спасибо, с меня плюсик :)

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю почему это влияет на работоспособность, но дело в названии функции.

```html
<button onclick="onClick()">Click</button>
<script>
function onClick() {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, дело в названии, попробуйте переименовать функцию:

```
function onClick() {
    console.log('click');
}
```